# How to pass getContext to Java class not working?

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

I am creating common java class for `ProgressBar` i getting error like below

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void app.bridgecenterandstaffmanagament.com.bridgecenterandstaffmanagament.CommonClass.Singletonclass_obj.showProgressBar(android.content.Context)' on a null object reference
                                                                                                                           at app.bridgecenterandstaffmanagament.com.bridgecenterandstaffmanagament.Fragments.NotificationFragment.onCreateView(NotificationFragment.java:41)
```

**Fragment**

```
public class NotificationFragment extends Fragment {


    public NotificationFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    RecyclerView recyclerView;



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notification, container, false);


        recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.recylierview_notification);



       // Singletonclass_obj.getInstance().showProgressBar(getActivity());
        Singletonclass_obj.getInstance().showProgressBar(getContext());
       // print();

        return v;
    }


}
```

**Java** class

```
public class Singletonclass_obj extends Application{
    private  ProgressBar progressBar;
    private static Singletonclass_obj singletonclassobj;



    public static Singletonclass_obj getInstance() {
        return singletonclassobj;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        singletonclassobj = this;
    }

    public void showProgressBar(Context context)
    {
      //  Toast.makeText(context, "welcometoindia", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        progressBar = new ProgressBar(context, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleSmall);
    }

    public void hideProgressBar()
    {
        if (progressBar !=null && progressBar.isShown())
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
     }

}
```

Same codeing working fine my last Project..please help me any one.

Comment: Why not use `Singletonclass_obj.getInstance().showProgressBar(getActivity());`?

Comment: You application implementation is already a singleton, there is no need to make it again.

Comment: @John Joe I tried not working sir.

Comment: @ Iulian Popescu I tried not working..my last project same code wrking sir..but why not working here i donot know,,please tell me what mistake i did

Comment: did you add **Singletonclass_obj** in manifest file as `android:name=""`

Comment: @NileshRathod it's java class sir,i am not able to add in manifest file.

Comment: @Mariyappan than why are your **extends Application** to your **Singletonclass_obj** class

Comment: @NileshRathod For  initialize SharedPreferences inside onCreate() ,,,I  `extends Application` removed also tried not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> as per my [above comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46169731/how-to-pass-getcontext-to-java-class-not-working#comment79301678_46169731) in question

try this add your `Singletonclass_obj` in to manifest file inside `application tag like below code`

```
<application
        android:name=".Singletonclass_obj"<!--add here your Singletonclass_obj class -->
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: it's working sir,but progress bar not showing,toast message is printing.

Comment: ProgressDialog is also showing but ProgressBar not showing.what was the problem sir.

Comment: ` progressBar = new ProgressBar(context, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleLarge);
      
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` inside singletonclass sir

Comment: `progressBar = new ProgressBar(context, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleLarge); progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` not showing why sir

Comment: Iulian Popescu, he told below answer it's not possible to show.

Comment: How to achieve ProgressBar is there any way sir,because Progress Dialog Deprecated.

Comment: @Mariyappan wait i'll update you

Comment: @Mariyappan  you won't be able to use the ProgressBar because you don't have a view to add in your `Singletonclass_obj`

Comment: ok thank you sir very much sir.

Comment: @Mariyappan most welcome happy to help you

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that you didn't initialise correctly the application class. Basically, the system doesn't know about your class and hence it is not created. You need to add the following in you `<application>` tag from `Manifest` and it will work:

```
android:name=".Singletonclass_obj"
```

and call it like this: `((Singletonclass_obj)getActivity().getApplication()).showProgressBar(getContext());`

However, as I said in comments, you don't need to create the application class as a singleton because it already is. So your application class would be something like this:

```
public class Singletonclass_obj extends Application {
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    public void showProgressBar(Context context)
    {
//          Toast.makeText(context, "welcometoindia", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        progressBar = new ProgressBar(context, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleSmall);
    }

    public void hideProgressBar()
    {
        if (progressBar !=null && progressBar.isShown())
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

}
```

Even if this will fix your issue regarding the NPE, you won't be able to use the `ProgressBar` because you don't have a view to add it (the application doesn't have a view).

Comment: Thank you sir,Toast message is printing but ProgressBar is not showing sir.

Comment: How to achieve ProgressBar is there any way sir,becase Progress Dialog Deprecated.